# Is there any documentation on JS trigger for the Gutenberg "Navigation" block?

Tags: menus, block-editor, navigation

I'm trying to programmatically trigger the close function on the Navigation block (I'm using [swup](https://swup.js.org/) and want to have the nav close when a new page dynamically loads). I see that it's using the InteractivityAPI library but can't find any documentation on how to trigger any of the built-in events programmatically.

Background: I'm in a child theme of Twenty Twenty Four theme.